# Jquery Table Body Not Displaying with SQL Data

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net, datatables

I am trying to pull data from my SQL database and display it in a Jquery DataTable. I was able to do this with a Gridview but now want to change to a Jquery DataTable for more functionality. It seems like the data is being collected in my BindGrid() function but it will not actually display in the table on the webpage, the headers show but no information below them.

Here is a picture of my web form right now: [image: No data is displaying in the datatable]

Also, here is all of my code as it stands now:

HTML:

```
<div style="margin-top:30px;">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="font-family: serif; border:1px;" id="netEventTable" clientIdMode="static">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th> 
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Subject Line</th>
                    <th>Start Time</th>
                    <th>Estimated Time of Resolution</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="netEventTableBody" runat="server">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#netEventTable').dataTable({
            "bLengthChange": true,
            "paging": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "jQueryUI": true,               
        });
    });
</script>
```

C# (CodeBehind):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.BindGrid();
        }
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        string strSQLConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        try
        {
            // Jquery DataTable
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strSQLConn);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getNetEvents", con);
            SqlDataReader user = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            String UnreadText = "";
            Int32 i = 0;
            while (user.Read())
            {
                UnreadText += "<tr>";
                UnreadText += "<td class=\'center'>" + user["ID"] + "</td>";
                UnreadText += "<td class=\'center'>" + user["Name"] + "</td>";
                UnreadText += "<td class=\'center'>" + user["Type"] + "</td>";
                UnreadText += "<td class=\'center'>" + user["SubjectLine"] + "</td>";
                UnreadText += "<td class=\'center'>" + user["StartTime"] + "</td>";
                UnreadText += "<td class=\'center'>" + user["EndTime"] + "</td>";
                UnreadText += "</tr>";
                i++;
            }
            con.Close();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.ToString());
            Helpers.ApplicationLogHelper.createApplicationLogError("ERROR", ex.ToString());
            return;
        }
    }
```

How can I get the data from my SQL server to display in the Jquery DataTable?

Comment: Where's your code that renders whatever (it seems) `UnreadText` contains to the front-end/HTML/aspx?

Comment: I don't think I have anything that renders it, how should I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing this part,

```
"ajax": {
        url: 'some url',
        type: "GET",
        error: function (data) {
            //catch error
        }
    }
```

because you are just initializing the jquery datatable so it won't do anything at all.

Comment: what would the url in my case be?

Comment: I assume your project is not asp.net mvc, so in that case this link might help you. https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx